# Host Serverless Jquery UI on AWS

Tags: python, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

we have our frontend in jquery and jinja templates, and we are calling APIs through AWS lambda. we already hosted our backend on lamda, is it possible to host the UI also on lambda given (jquery + jinja templates) used for UI. if it's possible may I know how to proceed with this?

Comment: I heard we can host only static websites on s3, how do we render dynamic templates on s3?

Comment: You are asking about "jquery UI" which is client-side rendered. Are you doing server-side dynamic content at all? You tagged the question with `python` but don't mention Python in your question at all.